# How do I export client side content to Word document via javascript?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, client

I'm familiar with generating office documents server-side by including the following at the top of the response:

```
<%
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "inline; filename = ASP_Word_Doc.doc"
%>
```

I'm currently facing the challenge of doing this purely client-side.  I've got an XSL transform that successfully generates valid Word XML.  Can anybody give me a pointer to how to reproduce this behaviour using purely client-side javascript?

I've found the document.open method, but that only supports text/html.

Ideally I'd like a cross-browser solution - but IE only would be a satisfactory fall-back

cheers,
Ian

Comment: What exactly is your question. How to generate the XML, or how to send the file for download?

Comment: @Unicron - Hi, it's the download part I'm struggling with.

Comment: then Downloadify should be for you.

Comment: @Unicron - thanks for the advice, except it doesn't meet the "using purely client-side javascript" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one part of your question, [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/) is a Flash-based JS helper library that lets you generate any kind of file for download locally.

Comment: thanks, but I'm afraid it doesn't meet the "using purely client-side javascript?" constraint

Comment: @ian to the best of my knowledge, it's not possible at all in pure client-side Javascript - that's the reason why that helper library exists. If that doesn't do for you, I think you will have to do an Ajax request to a server, send it the file data and request a file download back.